# Sorting dicom dataset in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, dicom

Hi have about 5000 2d images from multiple CT-scans and need to get them sorted. The dataset is directly imported from a GE workstation.

Right now the images are in bunches of about 10 sorted images at a time in some random order.

How could we get these images sorted? If you would suggest dicominfo please tell us exactly which parameter to  go after.

Thank you!

Comment: In what way would you like to get the images sorted? Do all images relate to the same patient and study?

Comment: If you are willing to use something other than Matlab you can find libraries that will make this work easier.  Consider the scanner provided by GDCM for example.

Answer (score 4):

How the DICOM CT images should be sorted is ultimately dependent on the usage context, but as a rule of thumb I would recommend that you first group the images based on (patient), study and series using these tags:

```
(0010,0020)  Patient ID
(0020,000D)  Study Instance UID
(0020,000E)  Series Instance UID
```

To sort the images within one series, you could use the *Instance Number (0020,0013)*, although there is no guarantee that this value is set since it is a type 2 attribute.

Another alternative is to use the *Image Position (Patient) (0020,0032)*, which is mandatory in CT images. You would need to check the *Image Orientation (Patient) (0020,0037)* to decide how to sort on position. Often CT image orientation is (1,0,0), (0,1,0), and then the Z (third) component of the image position can be used as the basis for sorting.

If the series also contains a localizer image, this image would have to be excluded from positional sorting.